# Add link-shared spreadsheet to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

Suppose someone shares a document with me (and others) using the public link sharing feature of Google Drive.

This link is set to allow edits from any user.

Can I get it to show up in my drive, perhaps under "shared with me" (like documents that are explicitly shared with my Google Account) such that it is searchable and easily accessible without finding the direct link?

Note that I don't want to "make a copy" to my drive.  It should update with the live document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ## What's in "Shared with me"
>
> “Shared with me” only lists files and folders that include your email
> address in their share settings. You won’t see files with share
> settings set to “Anyone with the link” or “Public.” Instead, try
> searching your Google Drive or looking for these items in the "All
> items" view (old Drive only).

Instead of "Shared with me" view use the Recent view. An alternative is to Star those files so you will find them in the Starred view.

**References**
["Shared with me" - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375057?hl=en)
[Google Drive's left-hand side navigation - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375046?hl=en)